# How to clone only a module from GIT?

Tags: git, github, github-for-mac

Suppose I have this [repository](https://github.com/pritambanerjee999/tutorials).

Now I want to clone only [this](https://github.com/pritambanerjee999/tutorials/tree/master/assertj) module and not the whole repository. If you clone the whole repository I can get it, but I don't want that.

What is the best way to do that, or is it at all possible to do so?

Comment: Git isn't Subversion. Those aren't modules or sub-repos. The whole thing is one repo, and you have to clone the whole thing to get the bits you want.

Comment: @cHao So I will have to clone the whole repo?

Comment: Looks like it, unless they have another git repo containing just that bit.

Comment: @cHao Ok. Got it. Then I guess I will have to clone the entire repo.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there any way to clone a git repository's sub-directory only?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/600079/is-there-any-way-to-clone-a-git-repositorys-sub-directory-only)

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28039894/6394138

Comment: If you need not a repository, but a snapshot of a single module from it, then you can obtain it with `git archive` as described here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25771130/6394138